# How to deal with specially "long" interfaces?

Tags: angular, typescript

Given the following interface with let say 10 or more properties

```
export interface EmployeeFilter {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  age: number;
  from: Date;
  to: Date;
  module: string;
  position: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  country: string;
}
```

Is there a way to initialize an object with the `EmployeeFilter` signature without explicitly set the properties?

> At the moment I have to manually initialize the properties:

```
const searchby: EmployeeFilter = {
  name: '',
  gender: '',
  age: 28,
  from: null,
  to: null,
  module: '',
  position: '',
  phone: '',
  email: '',
  country: ''
}
```

So I'm looking for an approach that automatically inits all the `EmployeeFilter` properties by setting it as `null`.
I've tried some ideas like:

```
const searchby: EmployeeFilter = new class implements EmployeeFilter{}();
```

But, for example by doing `console.log(searchby);` all I get is an empty object literal `{}`.

Comment: You can use the `as` keyword to use partials and maintain type safety: e.g. `const myPartial = {name: 'Biff'} as EmployeeFilter`.

Comment: just use a class?

Comment: Yup, seems like that's the only working approach.

Comment: @TheHeadRush - imho that's a bit "don't" - "type safety" means, that properties defined as "must be there" are there. "as" will not magically add these properties so safety is gone. Perhaps you mean Partial<EmployeeFilter>?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I'd agree that it's not a great idea in most situations, but the poster only asked if it could be done. A valid use case would be to test a method that takes an instance of `EmployeeFilter` as an argument but only manipulates a property or two.

Comment: @TheHeadRush, let's say this way: I'd call it a workaround or "quick fix" and yes, it could be ok in some situations to throw away type safety. But in general, I think it's something we really don't want to do. The good thing with interfaces is, that the compiler can help us - as long as we don't lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces exist only in the type system, and TypeScript types can never affect the emitted JavaScript.

Therefore, that is completely impossible based on just an interface.

However, you could replace the interface with a class.

Comment: Given that you can type your variables with classes, this is the best solution I can see.

Comment: great, my strange idea finally clarified :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a factory class that will return objects of `EmployeeFilter` type. You can also mark all fields in `EmployeeFilter` interface as optional, e.g. `name?: string;` etc. Then whenever you need some EmployeeFilter, the factory can return it with default values. You cannot create an instance of an interface or cast it to a class somehow because interfaces don't exist in the runtime. They only exist during compilation time for type checking.